# Set form responses sheet name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am creating a form dynamically and binding it to a spreadsheet via `FormApp.create().setDestination(...)`. Is it possible to give / change the name that the linked sheet gets? (`Form Responses 9` isn't really informativ in my case).

Since I didn't find anything in the API for naming the sheet, I'm thinking of going and finding the sheet, but I don't know its name in advance, just that it is of the format `/Form Responses \d/`.

How should I go about this?

Comment: Can't you just check the names of the available sheets when created? For example get the sheet names, iterate through them, if they start with form responses add them to a list. Go thorough that list and check the numbers on the end by splitting the string. Whatever is the highest number you can assume the next one created is just an increment of one. Then you can just change the name.

Comment: You can use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51484165/9337071) or Ruben's answer to find the specific sheet, and then standard Apps Script `Sheet` methods as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `getSheets()` to get a collection of Sheets then use `getFormUrl()` on each of them, then on the sheet that return the right form URL you could use `getName()` to get the current sheet name or `setName(name)` to set the name that you want.

The above because the `setDestination` method of Class Form doesn't include a way to set the name of the destination sheet.